# C++ why my program does not work...:S

Tags: c++

this is my program...
am trying to read 2D points from a file by loop and find each time the distance from another point r(x,y). All the data have to get in from files...

the file witch contains the "r" is called  Robot_point.dat and is just a file with 2 numbers separated by space:

4 2.5

the file witch contains the points is called Polygons.dat and is formed like that:

5
1 2
2 1
3 2
2.5 3
2 3

the number 5 reference to the number of the points(actually vertices of a polygon). Each pair of numbers is a point.

I wrote this program but....it does not working and I do not understand why as I am new at C++

```
#include <math.h>
#include <iostream>
#include <cmath>
#incude <fstream>



using namespace std;

int main()
{
double r[2];
double point[2];
double Dis;
int N;


ifstream fin;
fin.open("Robot_Point.dat");
fin>> r[0]>>r[1];
fin.close();

cout<<"Robots reference point is:  "<<r[0]<<" , "<<r[1]<<endl;

fin.open("Polygons.dat");
fin>>N;



int i=0;
while(i<N)
{
    fin>>point[0]<<point[1];

    Dis=sqrt(pow((r[0]-point[0]),2)-pow((r[1]-point[1]),2));

    i++;

    cout<<"Dis ="<<Dis<<endl;
}
fin.close();

return 0;

}
```

Comment: What does it do instead ?

Comment: its just did not compile....:

Comment: compiler prints errors where I do not understand...something about the arrays...:S

Comment: Then you should clearly state that your program dos not *compile* ("does not work" is way too vague to be meaningful), and copy-paste the compiler's error message here. Help us help you ;)

Answer (score 2):

You have 2 typos:

Replace `#incude` by `#include` and `fin>>point[0]<<point[1];` by `fin>>point[0]>>point[1];`

The compiler warnings/errors are not the most illuminating (especially when dealing with templates like `ostream& operator<<`), but you'll learn to read them in time.

Comment: really really thenks...:))) now is working

Answer (score 0):

In this line:

```
fin>>point[0]<<point[1];
```

You probably meant:

```
fin>>point[0]>>point[1];
```

Also, you should change `#incude` to `#include`.

Answer (score 0):

This is obviously wrong

`fin>>point[0]<<point[1];`

Replace with

`fin>>point[0]>>point[1];`

Here is a simple tutorial about Basic IO

http://www.cplusplus.com/doc/tutorial/basic_io/